# Unable to change sitecore context language in SXA JSS site

Tags: sxa, multilingual

I have a Sitecore JSS site with SXA. In my Site Grouping item, I've chosen the language as en-ca. Now, I've written a pipeline to change my context language under certain conditions. It's working fine in my local environment, which doesn't have the SXA Site Grouping item. However, when I move the code to a higher environment where SXA is enabled and en-ca is set as the default language in the CD site grouping item, it always loads the site in en-ca.

If I send null in the default language field, the site throws a 502 error as the Sitecore context language becomes null.

```
<httpRequestBegin>
<processor type="Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.PostStepsRunner.AbortRequestOnPackageMaintenance, Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.PostStepsRunner" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Cloud.Integration.Bootload.PostStepsRunner.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.PreprocessRequest.CheckIgnoreFlag, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.EnsureServerUrl, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.StartMeasurements, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.IgnoreList, Sitecore.Kernel" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Horizon.config">
<prefixes hint="list">
<prefix name="identityProcessing" patch:source="Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.config">/identity/</prefix>
<prefix name="service" patch:source="Sitecore.GraphQL.config">/sitecore/api/authoring/</prefix>
<prefix name="sxa" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Horizon.config">/sxa/horizon/</prefix>
</prefixes>
</processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DisplayFatalErrors, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SiteResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ResolveSite, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" patch:source="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.SetRuntimeSettings, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.CheckMode, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.UserResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ResolveUserFromRequest, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DatabaseResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.SxaSitemapHandler, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.RobotsHandler, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SiteMetadata.config">
<CacheExpiration>720</CacheExpiration>
</processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.BeginDiagnostics, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.EnableCreativeExchangeMode, Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.CreativeExchange.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Json.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ResolveJsonDevice, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Json" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Json.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.DeviceResolver.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.MultiAgentDeviceResolver, Sitecore.XA.Feature.DeviceResolver" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.DeviceResolver.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LanguageResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ResolveLanguage, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.CustomHandlers, Sitecore.Kernel">
<param type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HandlerMapping.DirectHandlerMapper, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
</processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HandleActionRequest, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.QueryStringResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DynamicLinkResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.AliasResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DefaultResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.FileResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.DeviceSimulator.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HandleSimulationRequest, Sitecore.Mvc.DeviceSimulator" patch:source="Sitecore.MVC.DeviceSimulator.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferRoutedRequest, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.SkipContextItemResolutionWhenLayoutServiceRequest, Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.LayoutService.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.Hosting.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.SkipContextItemResolutionWhenGraphQLRequest, Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.NetFxHost" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.Services.GraphQL.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.CultureResolver, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.SitecoreExtensions.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Redirects.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.RedirectItem, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Redirects" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Redirects.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Redirects.Pipelines.HttpRequest.RedirectMapResolver, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Redirects" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Redirects.config">
<CacheExpiration>720</CacheExpiration>
</processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LocalizableUrlItemResolver, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.config">
<CacheExpiration>5</CacheExpiration>
</processor>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.ItemNotFoundResolver, Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.Pipelines.HttpRequest.HeadlessSiteAccess, Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.JavaScriptServices.ViewEngine.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ResolveContentLanguage, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Multisite.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LaunchRequest, Sitecore.ItemWebApi" patch:source="Sitecore.ItemWebApi.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.DeviceSimulatorResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Overlays.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.OverlayTypeResolver, Sitecore.XA.Feature.Overlays" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.Overlays.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.AppendCompatibilityModeHeader, Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Foundation.Theming.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.LayoutResolver, Sitecore.Kernel"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.LayoutNotFoundResolver, Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.ErrorHandling.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Integration.Pipelines.HttpRequestBegin.AppPathNotFoundResolver, Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Integration" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.JSS.Foundation.Integration.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.PageEditorHandleNoLayout, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.DeviceResolver.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Pipelines.HttpRequest.CheckDevice, Sitecore.ExperienceEditor" resolve="true" patch:source="Sitecore.XA.Feature.DeviceResolver.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferMvcLayout, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.HttpRequest.TransferControllerRequest, Sitecore.Mvc" patch:source="Sitecore.Mvc.config"/>
<processor type="Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ExecuteRequest, Sitecore.Kernel" resolve="true"/>
</httpRequestBegin>
```

I'm unsure where to place my pipeline in the httpRequestBegin pipeline to override the SXA default language set in the site grouping item.

Comment: If it works locally, but not on the upper environment, then your patch probably didn't get deployed correctly.

Comment: In my local I'm using connected mode without SXA Site grouping item whereas in upper env , I'm using headless mode with SXA and Site Grouping Item